# Validation of encrypted data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, encryption, attr-encrypted

I encrypt all private data of users before storing in database with help of gem 'attr_encrypted'. For example, I have 'email_addresses' table, which contains 'encrypted_email' column. This gem decrypt data when I call object.email or when I search by emails. But I have issues with validation of this column.

I have following validations for this and other tables:

```
validates_length_of :email, :within => 3..100
validates_numericality_of :post_code
```

I should decrypt data before validation somehow, but I don't know how to do this with help of built-in Rails tools. I don't want invent custom validations for this. Please, advise.

Answer (score 0):

validations that doesn't need a db query run on the rails side so you can pass a method instead of a column to the validation methods

```
validates :decrypted_email, length: { within: 3..100 }

def decrypted_email
  # decrypt email here
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work for all types of validations. For example validates_uniqueness_of checks if name of passed method is included in [column_hash](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/columns_hash/class) (i.e. in the appropriate database table) and it raises exception if the method is not there.