# Performing rails model validations before encrypting attribute with attr-encrypted gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, encryption, attr-encrypted

I have an encrypted attribute (let's call it @model.encrypted_attribute) in one of my models.  Before adding encryption I had the following validation in my model:

```
validates_length_of :attribute, :minimum => 11, :maximum => 11, :allow_blank => true, 
:message => "| Your attribute must be 11 digits long."
```

I also had a method that ran `before_save` that would gsub out all non-numerical characters from the attribute.  Now, however, I can't figure out how to:

1. Run `gsub!(/\D/, '')` on the attribute before it is encrypted and saved OR run it afterwards and have attr-encrypted re-encrypt the `@model.attribute` value and write it back to the database.  I can strip the characters, but not re-encrypt/save.
2. Run the validation on the non-encrypted value of `attribute` before saving.  I have tried adding the following code in a before_block but I then get the a different error (`undefined method '12345678' for #<Spree::Order:0x007fae02011cd0`):

   ```
     def format_attribute
       validates_length_of self.attribute.gsub(/\D/, ''), :minimum => 9, :maximum => 9, :allow_blank => true, :message =>
       "| Your attribute should be 9 digits long."
   end
   ```

Does anyone have an idea of how I can achieve one or both of the above or, at the very least, set a custom method to run before attr_encrypted does its thing.

-------------edit-------------
Leaving two above for people who come into this while searching but the solution for it can be found at [Validation of encrypted data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178789/validation-of-encrypted-data)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validation of encrypted data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178789/validation-of-encrypted-data)